# Conversion of date format using sed or awk

Tags: date, unix, awk, sed, format

I am new to unix and i am searching for an answer for the below problem.

I have a semi colon delimited file as below

```
Frank;01012019;01012020;woodcrest wack st
Mark;01012019;01012020;Annunciation st
Fred;01022019;01012020;Baker st
```

The date format in the input file is in DDMMYYYY format. I need the date to be converted into YYYYMMDD format as below.

Expected Output:

```
Frank;20190101;20200101;woodcrest wack st
Mark;20190101;20200101;Annunciation st
Fred;20190201;20200101;Baker st
```

Please suggest me answers using sed or awk command.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I tried many variants suggested in various websites..none seemed to work..

Comment: @sadhiyausama, you need to mention error what you are getting while running commands here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Perl

```
$ cat sadhiya.txt
Frank;01012019;01012020;woodcrest wack st
Mark;01012019;01012020;Annunciation st
Fred;01022019;01012020;Baker st

$ perl -F";" -lane ' s/(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})/$3$2$1/g for @F[1..2]; print join(";",@F) ' sadhiya.txt
Frank;20190101;20200101;woodcrest wack st
Mark;20190101;20200101;Annunciation st
Fred;20190201;20200101;Baker st
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/;([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/;\3\2\1/g' file.csv
```

Output:

```
Frank;20190101;20200101;woodcrest wack st
Mark;20190101;20200101;Annunciation st
Fred;20190201;20200101;Baker st
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F';' '{print $1";"substr($2, 5, 4)""substr($2, 1, 2)""substr($2, 0, 2)";"substr($3, 5, 4)""substr($3, 1, 2)""substr($3, 0, 2)";"$4}' file
```

Comment: In addition a slightly different notation with the same result: `awk -F';' '$0=$1 FS substr($2, 5, 4) substr($2, 1, 2) substr($2, 0, 2) FS substr($3, 5, 4) substr($3, 1, 2) substr($3, 0, 2) FS $4' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4});/\3\2\1;/g' data
#=> Frank;20190101;20200101;woodcrest wack st
#=> Mark;20190101;20200101;Annunciation st
#=> Fred;20190201;20200101;Baker st
```

`\1`, `\2`, and `\3` represent each parenthesis catched content, i.e. the `DD`, `MM`, and `YYYY` here. `s` is to replace in `sed`.
The `g` at last means to replace all occurances, without it sed will only replace first group.

If the input is formatted and stable like you said, then `sed` is actually easier to do this.
ps: `-E` is for `extended regular expressions`, it works both on unix sed and GNU sed.
It relieves you the needs to escape `(){}`.

Comment: Actually, back-references `\1` are defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). The problem of not using `-E` is that with only BRE, you need to use `\( ... \)` and `\{ ... \}`. Anyway, your answer seems to be a copy of [Cyrus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935811/9136541) :/

Comment: @mickp  Thanks, updated.  Our answer time are very close. Also OP mentioned unix, so I tested on unix before hand.  I just added some explanation for it, for OP and anyone else who needed :)

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E -n 's/(.*);([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4});([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4});(.*)/\1;\4\3\2;\7\6\5;\8/p' file_name
```